# Kivy Button image - in this code one graphic displays correct size, the other one doesn't. Why?

Tags: python-3.x, image, button, kivy

I've got two Buttons and I'm assigning an image to each.  The first button that appears in the code here displays at the correct size and looks good.  The other looks squashed.  Are the image dimensions tied to the "text" size, and if so, how can I free it so it displays the correct size?
(I tried allow_stretch, keep_ratio, no change.  I changed size_hint, it changed the *position* of the oval not its size!)
Here's the .kv code:

```
Button:
    id: MAmount_Button_Three
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .75, "center_y": .57}
    size_hint: .19,.09
    halign: "left"
    Image:
        id: MAmount_Three_Image
        source: 'ButtonOutline_RightSize.png'
        pos: MAmount_Button_Three.pos[0]-dp(5), MAmount_Button_Three.pos[1]-dp(10)
    Label:
        id: MAmount_Label_Three
        pos: MAmount_Button_Three.pos[0]-dp(5), MAmount_Button_Three.pos[1]-dp(10)
        text: "20%"

Button:
    id: MAmount_Button_Four
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .45}
    size_hint: .19,.09
    halign: "left"
    Image:
        id: MAmount_Four_Image
        #allow_stretch: True
        #keep_ratio: True
        source: 'LongButtonOutline_RightSize.png'
        pos: MAmount_Button_Four.pos[0]-dp(5), MAmount_Button_Four.pos[1]-dp(10)
    Label:
        id: MAmount_Label_Four
        pos: MAmount_Button_Four.pos[0]-dp(5), MAmount_Button_Four.pos[1]-dp(10)
        text: "Custom"
```

Here's what it looks like. If I look a the Custom oval compared to the percentage circle in Photoshop, the Custom oval is the same height, but much longer.
[image]

[image]

Comment: `Button` is not a container. Try using a container, like `FloatLayout`.

Comment: Further up my kv code I have FloatLayout. Here's my hirarchy:  `MDScreen:  MDFloatLayout:  Button:   Image:`

Comment: OK, I moved `Image:` and `Label:` to the same indentation level as `Button:`  , and now it works.